# The argument type 'Set<Marker>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Set<Marker>'

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies

When i try to assign set of markers to markers argument in GoogleMap it gives me this error...[image]
The argument type 'Set?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Set'.

Code Sample

```
body: GoogleMap(
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(
        widget.initialLocation!.latitude!,
        widget.initialLocation!.longitude!,
      ),
      zoom: 16,
    ),
    onTap: widget.isSelecting! ? _selectLocation : null,
    
    markers: _pickedLocation == null
        ? null
        : {
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
              position: _pickedLocation!,
            ),
          },
  ),
```

Comment: It's a nullable vs non-nullable check.  Your actual can be null and the parameter type does not allow it.

Comment: How i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
markers: (_pickedLocation == null && !widget.isSelecting)
        ? <Marker>[].toSet()
        : [
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
              position: _pickedLocation ??
                  LatLng(
                    widget.initialLocation.latitude!,
                    widget.initialLocation.longitude!,
                  ),
            ),
          ].toSet(),
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an empty set which will satisfy the non-null requirement of the markers: property

```
markers: (_pickedLocation == null && !widget.isSelecting)
        ? {}
        : [
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
              position: _pickedLocation ??
                  LatLng(
                    widget.initialLocation.latitude!,
                    widget.initialLocation.longitude!,
                  ),
            ),
          ].toSet(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the marker value this way

```
markers: _pickedLocation == null
            ? <Marker>[].toSet()
            : [
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
            position: _pickedLocation!,
          ),
        ].toSet(),
```